# Node.js express app fails to redirect from dropzone.js callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, dropzone.js

I am trying to add a dropzone.js powered drag and drop upload page to my node.js app which uses express/jade templates to create its pages. The issue I am having is that it seems that there is no way for me to redirect the user from the dropzone callback.

Here is my jade file that creates the dropzone (note the scipts and css are loaded in layout):

```
extend layout
block content
    div(id="dropzone")
        form(method="POST" action="upload" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone")
```

Here is my very simple callback:

```
app.post("/upload", function(req, res) {
    console.log("UPLOAD POST");
    res.redirect("/");
    //project.finishUpload(db, req, res);
});
```

I see the print from the console.log but it never redirects back to the root.

Also, here are my Dropzone options:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
  paramName: "file",
  maxFilesize: 10, 
  acceptedFiles: "application/zip"
};
```

What could I do to cause a redirect from my Dropzone callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform the redirect in your client-side code because you're making an AJAX form submission, not a normal browser-based form submission.

```
app.post("/upload", function(req, res) {
    console.log("UPLOAD POST");
    res.status(201).end()
});
```

And on the client-side:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
  paramName: "file",
  maxFilesize: 10, 
  acceptedFiles: "application/zip",
  init: function(){
    this.on("success", function(){
      window.location.pathname = "/";
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! There doesn't seem to be a function sendStatus in the response, I get the error: Object #<ServerResponse> has no method 'sendStatus'.

Comment: Yeah, just change that to `res.status(201).end()`.

Comment: Ah, perfect thanks! I changed it in your answer which I have also accepted.